# Set limitation on gap tolerance and run time

Tags: csv, optimization, runtime, cplex, ibm-ilog-opl

I have two questions:

1. In IBM ILOG CPLEX, I wrote an OPL project. Because the code works with large scale data, it takes a lot of time to solve. What is the code for limitation the gap tolerance of MIP Problem and limitation the time?
2. I want to have a CSV file containing my desired results. For example, I want to have an objective function and runtime and the facility variable in a CSV file. I got all these results but I want them to be written in a CSV file too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)  Add the following code *before* the `minimize` statement in your `.mod` file.

```
execute
{
   cplex.tilim=30; // 20 s time limt
   cplex.epgap=0.01 // 1% gep
}
```

You can confirm that it is taken into account by examining the engine log. It should have something like this at the very beginning:

```
CPXPARAM_TimeLimit                               30
CPXPARAM_MIP_Tolerances_MIPGap                   0.01
```

2) You may rely on IloOplOutputFile

See example in https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=3fd44d41-210b-4b81-a005-819530d6377b&ps=25

Comment: Thanks for your response. My problem for writing results in CSV file is that one of the things is a variable y=[10000101010] and I just want to write indexes of the columns equal to 1. Do you have any idea? Also when I use cplex.tilim in my code it doesn't affect and my code run so much longer than what I want.

Comment: See the example warehouse.mod {int} Storesof[w in Warehouses] = { s | s in Stores : Supply[s][w] == 1 }; is an example on how to get all indexes with value 1

Comment: Instead of writing the parameter settings in your code, you may also use a settings (OPS) file.

Comment: I tried this code and in engine log, it's exactly brought my desired limitation. But the solution time that I get from my code is more than the limitation that I choose.